# É possível recuperar o src de um arquivo .WAR implantado?

Tags: java, compiladores, jvm, war

Estou trabalhando com um monte de aplicações legadas aqui. Uma delas (em produção) precisa ser editada porque não tem nenhum log.

Eu decompilei, mas eu não tenho ideia sobre como remontar nesta situação. Eu não pude se quer recompilar as classes individuais editadas por causa da otimização do compilador.
(Estou usando Java 6)

Comment: Não é possível chegar aos fontes originais através desse processo.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo se refere ao fato de que mesmo recompilando sem editar, o "novo" binário vai estar diferente do anterior?

Comment: Não. Se você conseguir compilar como esta, o binário será igual.

Answer (score -1):

Não, descobri que é impossível (até a data de hoje) fazer esse processo. Existem várias formas de recuperar o código para ler usando decompiladores, até mesmo online, mas editar esse artefato e reenviar para deploy não é viável.

Como meu caso era necessário apenas monitorar o conteúdo, ou seja, não tinham novas funcionalidades para ser implementadas. Dar a volta no problema usando JAMon e AspectJ foi o suficiente.
Segue um tutorial muito, muito simples sobre a técnica. http://keylesson.com/index.php/2015/12/16/monitoring-java-application-with-aspectj-and-jamon-2576/